# "Xaml Parsing Failed" on Windows Store Apps User Control Project

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I must be missing something simple/fundamental that I failed to reference a Windows Store Apps Class Library/Windows Runtime Component in my Windows Store Apps Project.

I stripped everything down to it's bare-bone state. This is what I've got:

**The User Control Project (DummyItem.xaml):**

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Grid Background="Red">

  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**My Windows Store Apps' MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Page ...
  xmlns:c="using:Midas.UI.Cards">

  <Canvas Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
      <c:DummyItem Width="150" Height="100"></c:DummyItem>
  </Canvas>
</Page>
```

I am able to build the project, but upon running it says "XAML Parsing Failed". I am not able to preview the control on the MainPage.xaml's designer, it says "Can't create an instance of DummyItem".

I've been experiencing this problem since Visual Studio 11 RC, and had to release my apps with all the user controls' code replicated in the Windows Store Apps project itself for it to work. Can any kind soul point me at the correct direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It´s a known issue in Visual Studio 2012. The problem appears, if the assembly´s name contains a dot. See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/fa2d8d53-254c-4d4a-b39a-110fde0d6c80

Comment: got it. the fix recommended on the site does not work either. But at least now I know how to avoid the problem. Thanks a bunch mate!

Comment: You´re right. I cam along your post when I ran into the same problem. I just changed the name of the output assembly, which fixed the problem.

Comment: I wish I could buy you a drink!

Comment: No problem; just let me know when you´re visiting Germany next time (-: